# Asp net mvc 4 Kendo dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a kendo drop down list it binds on page load.

I have a filter section and I filter one drop down list and I click the submit button and its submitting the page.

When I am clicking the submit button I validates the drop down list whether the user selects the valid input or user types invalid data.

When I clicking the submit button, I save the valid data in hidden field and assigns the value to model property.

After submits the page the selected value(before submits) is selected in dropdownlist.

If now I submit the page once again the drop down list selected index comes as -1.

How to validate this drop down list in the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it's value from model when rendering the page again.
You can easily set by following way using jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      var dropdownlist = $("#movies").data("kendoDropDownList")
      dropdownlist.value($("#value").val());
 });
```